# About Bhuthathan's birth from Halahala poison

Tags: scripture, shiva

Most of us know that Lord Shiva swallowed the Halahala. But, I have recently heard that a being called Bhuthathan was born from that poison. (You can learn about him from **[here](https://hindupad.com/swamy-sangili-boothathar/)**)

AFAIK, the Maha Puranas mentiones that it was 100% swallowed by Lord Shiva.

So, my question is, Did Upa Puranas or any other scriptures mentiones about Bhuthathan's birth from Halahala (*possibly they can mention Bhutathan in another name*) or it is just a folklore?

Comment: Shiva never swallowed poison (Halahala) during Samudra Manthan because it could cause some damage to his body ( which may need his later remedial action ) nor can he allow it to pollute/destroy the whole world. So he half swallowed it (not 100% ) holding it midway in his neck turning it blue, as NeelaKanta.

Comment: Oh, i forgot that point. Thanks for reminds me . But, What about Bhuthathan?

Comment: This Bhuthathan or Bhuthanathan ( animator? ) name  is new  to me, not included in the list of milk churned appearances. May be you can cite references for others to find him out from among standard scriptures.

Comment: Seems like a folklore to me